# Order of the Big-O's?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

My order by their Big-O order would be: 8,5,3,1,2,7,6,4. Would this be the correct order?

1. $f(n) = C$ where $C$ is some constant
2. $f(n) = \log (n) $
3. $f(n) = n^6 $
4. $f(n) = n! $
5. $f(n) = 6^n $
6. $f(n) = 5n \log (n)$
7. $f(n) = \log(2n)$
8. $f(n) = 6n$

Comment: Your order is not correct. Recall $c\ll \log(x)\ll x \ll c^x \ll x!$

Comment: The appearance of constant in the middle of your order seems weird

Comment: You'll want to revisit this. Please, plot each of these functions so you can see what the graphs look like. It's not a formal method to establish correctness, but it should give you an intuitive sense of how these functions behave, which is a good first step.

Comment: Hint: Two of these are of the same order

Comment: If a function is closer to the y axis (the operations axis), do I consider that more efficient?